# changing button's text after click vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is kinda simple, and really silly. but I can't see what I am missing..

```
    Private Sub btnmode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmode.Click
    If Me.btnmode.Text = "COMMAND MODE" Then
        Me.btnmode.Text = "DATA MODE"
        sPort.Write("$$$")
    End If
    If Me.btnmode.Text = "DATA MODE" Then
        Me.btnmode.Text = "COMMAND MODE"
        sPort.Write("$$$" & vbCr)
        sPort.Write("exit" & vbCr)
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

with this code, I should be able to change its text after clicking. but why is it not? nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Me.btnLoad.Text = "COMMAND MODE" Then
    Me.btnLoad.Text = "DATA MODE"
    sPort.Write("$$$")
ElseIf Me.btnLoad.Text = "DATA MODE" Then
    Me.btnLoad.Text = "COMMAND MODE"
    sPort.Write("$$$" & vbCr)
    sPort.Write("exit" & vbCr)
End If
```

Comment: goodness gracious. hahaha! thanks. why doesn't it read two If's ? lol

Comment: It is straight fowrard that if the button one has predefined text do some action and disconnects that loop..But for else statement if it has some text it looks for that and changes it and tries to execute the next step

Answer (score 1):

Use a [select case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cy37t14y.aspx) in this situation, It will be more readable.

```
select case ucase(Me.btnmode.Text)

case "COMMAND MODE"
    Me.btnmode.Text = "DATA MODE"
    sPort.Write("$$$")
case "DATA MODE"
    Me.btnmode.Text = "COMMAND MODE"
    sPort.Write("$$$" & vbCr)
    sPort.Write("exit" & vbCr)

End Select
```

**Problems** found in your code:

```
    If Me.btnmode.Text = "COMMAND MODE" Then
        Me.btnmode.Text = "DATA MODE" '--------> Text been set as DATA MODE
        sPort.Write("$$$")            '    |
    End If                            '    |
                                      '    |
   If Me.btnmode.Text = "DATA MODE" Then ' ---------> Here again                                       
       Me.btnmode.Text = "COMMAND MODE"  '    you are checking the Text with 
       sPort.Write("$$$" & vbCr)         '    DATA MODE and you are assigning
       sPort.Write("exit" & vbCr)        '    the text back to COMMAND MODE
   End If
```

So i guess initially your button's text is set with "COMMAND MODE". As a result, your button's text is refusing to revert back.

Comment: oh, that's why only one condition worked. silly mistake. thanks for the explanation!